# How to return subject when deleted with laravel spatie activity log

Tags: php, laravel, activitylog

I'm using [laravel-activitylog](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v3/introduction).
When a record is deleted the `$activity->subject` is `null`.
On `updated` and `created` the `$activity->subject` returns the model object.

Is there any way I can return the subject on `deleted` too?

Answer (score 0):

you can use soft-delete where actual record should not be deleted and you can able to pass the deleted object

Comment: I would prefer not to use soft-delete. Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: before deleting records you can store the record into cache but i suggest with soft delete its much more comfortable